# How to delay onServiceConnected call

Tags: android, service

I'm implementing `Service` that establishes TCP connection with server and then allows clients to pass messages through this connection. Clients connect to service with `bindService` call. As a result `onServiceConnected` called in clients `ServiceConnection` object. The problem is that `onServiceConnected` called right after return from `bindService`, but my `Service` was not established connection with server at this moment. Can I somehow delay `onServiceConnected` call while connection was not established? If it is not possible please suggest some good pattern for my case. Thank you.

Comment: There are two connections.  One app<->Service, which can and should immediately connect.  Separately, the Service should connect to the server. There are should be two connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it as follows:

Service code:

```
class MyService implements Service {
    private boolean mIsConnectionEstablished = false;

    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MyService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public
            // methods
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    public interface OnConnectionEstablishedListener {
        public void onConnectionEstablished();
    }

    private OnConnectionEstablishedListener mListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

       new Thread( new Runnable() {
           @Override
           void run() {
               //Connect to the server here

               notifyConnectionEstablished();
           }
       }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private void notifyConnectionEstablished() {
        mIsConnectionEstablished = true;

        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onConnectionEstablished();
        }
    }


    public void setOnConnectionEstablishedListener(
        OnConnectionEstablishedListener listener) {

        mListener = listener

        // Already connected to server. Notify immediately.
        if(mIsConnectionEstablished) {
            mListener.onConnectionEstablished();
        }
    }
}
```

Activity code:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements ServiceConnection,
    OnConnectionEstablishedListener {

    private MyService mService;
    private boolean mBound;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

       //bind the service here
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
       bindService(intent, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;

        mService.setOnConnectionEstablishedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionEstablished() {
        // At this point the service has been bound and connected to the server
        // Do stuff here
        // Note: This method is called from a non-UI thread.
    }
}
```

Comment: You are saving an Activity instance on a Service. This is not the correct approach. The Activity is more prone to dead than Service, so you could have a NPE. Maybe if you remove at onResume or onStop on Activity...